# why float left is not working on last element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I create a horizontal list using `float:left` .It is working fine in all element but not working in last element . I have already trying `clear:both`.but it not working.

Actually I the problem is all element have `101px` height . but last item or last `li` increase it's height to `303px` .I am thinking float left not working.

here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/74scu286/1/

I am using like this

```
 .rh08-slider__slide {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
```

my only concern was why  last element increase it's height as it has same content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body class="f20 f20v0 ready" style="opacity:1">
<div class="f20w1">

    <section class="rh08 rh08v0 rw-neutral-50bg" data-trackas="rh08" data-ocomid="rh08">
        <div class="rh08-slider rh08-slider-1 is-draggable rh08-slider_ready" data-custom-id="rh08-slider-1">


            <div class="rh08-slider__slides-container">
                <div class="rh08-slider__track" style="width: 8454px; transform: translate3d(-1409px, 0px, 0px);">
                    <div class="rh08-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="1" style="width: 16.6667%;">
                        <div class="rh08w1 cpad">
                            <div class="rh08w2 rh02txt">
                                <div class="rh08w5">
                                    <div class="rh08w6">
                                        <h2 class="rwaccent-4">4 Premier League wählt Oracle Cloud als Grundlage für
                                            neue, fortschrittliche Fußballanalysen</h2>
                                        <p>Das Gesundheitsmanagementsystem des australischen Bundesstaates digitalisiert
                                            die Patientenaufnahme und verwaltet gleichzeitig Gesundheitsakten und
                                            Impfstoffbestände sicher.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rh08w1 cpad rh08-slider__slide slick-active" data-crystal-slide="2"
                         style="width: 16.6667%;">


                        <div class="rh08w2 rh02txt">
                            <div class="rh08w5">
                                <div class="rh08w6">
                                    <h2 class="rwaccent-4">Premier League wählt Oracle Cloud als Grundlage für neue,
                                        fortschrittliche Fußballanalysen</h2>
                                    <p>Das Gesundheitsmanagementsystem des australischen Bundesstaates digitalisiert die
                                        Patientenaufnahme und verwaltet gleichzeitig Gesundheitsakten und
                                        Impfstoffbestände sicher.</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="rh08w1 cpad rh08-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="3" style="width: 16.6667%;">
                        <div class="rh08w2 rh02txt">
                            <div class="rh08w5">
                                <div class="rh08w6">
                                    <h2 class="rwaccent-4">2 Premier League wählt Oracle Cloud als Grundlage für neue,
                                        fortschrittliche Fußballanalysen</h2>
                                    <p>Das Gesundheitsmanagementsystem des australischen Bundesstaates digitalisiert die
                                        Patientenaufnahme und verwaltet gleichzeitig Gesundheitsakten und
                                        Impfstoffbestände sicher.</p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--      <div class="crsl-nav slick-nav "><a class="slick-prev slick-arrow slick-disabled" data-lbl="prev-slide" aria-label="Previous" aria-disabled="true" style="">Previous</a><a class="slick-next slick-arrow o-hf" data-lbl="next-slide" aria-label="Next" style="" aria-disabled="false">Next</a><ul class="slick-dots hide" role="tablist"><li class="slick-active" role="presentation"><button type="button" aria-pressed="true" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control00" aria-controls="slick-slide00" aria-label="1 of 2" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">1</button></li><li role="presentation"><button type="button" aria-pressed="false" role="tab" id="slick-slide-control01" aria-controls="slick-slide03" aria-label="2 of 2" tabindex="-1">2</button></li></ul></div>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="rh08-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="6" style="width: 16.6667%;">
                        <div class="rh08w1 cpad rh08-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="2" style="width: 16.6667%;">

                            <div class="rh08w2 rh02txt">
                                <div class="rh08w5">
                                    <div class="rh08w6">
                                        <h2 class="rwaccent-4">Premier League wählt Oracle Cloud als Grundlage für neue,
                                            fortschrittliche Fußballanalysen</h2>
                                        <p>Das Gesundheitsmanagementsystem des australischen Bundesstaates digitalisiert
                                            die Patientenaufnahme und verwaltet gleichzeitig Gesundheitsakten und
                                            Impfstoffbestände sicher.</p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <!-- /RH08v0 -->


</div>


</body>

</html>
```

My issue is related to height .Actually last element increase it's height. it should be same as `101px` as other slide

updated link https://jsfiddle.net/74scu286/1/

Comment: `here is my code` - it does not look close to the other code you posted. Please use the `<>` snippet tool when you edit your question to make a working example of the problem.

Comment: Floating elements need to come *before* elements that are supposed to render around the floating element. Also your code link is not what you want to present.

Comment: @connexo so how to fix that

Comment: Don't use `float` for layouts. Use flexbox or grid instead. We're not in 2005 any more.

Comment: @connexo I am sharing my code I think it is not visible

Comment: see my code ..https://jsfiddle.net/74scu286/1/

Comment: see my updated code link https://jsfiddle.net/74scu286/1/

Comment: @user5711656 Is the example in the link working? It don't do anything except show the first text.

Comment: Please remove all jsfiddle links and put your code in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Please also click "Tidy".

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it is static HtML.. I am creating static page

Answer (score 0):

Your floats are working fine.

However, your final floated div has this extra div within it which the others don't have:

```
<div class="rh08w1 cpad rh08-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="2" style="width: 16.6667%;">
```

This means you are putting the width down by 16.6667% twice so it's narrower, thus taller.

Comment: thanks for answering .. but same thing happening in first item also. but first item  has same height why ?

Comment: No, look closely. The first item has just one div with 16.6667%, the last item contains an extra div which also has 16.667% set, so the text element goes smaller by that amount again.